# RODBC with shiny error

Tags: r, shiny

I want to connect to Access database introducing the URL in a textInput.

the server code is as follow:

```
function(input, output) {

    dataframe <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    db <- renderPrint({ input$text })

    con <- odbcConnectAccess(db())
    info <- sqlTables(channel = con, tableType = "TABLE")$TABLE_NAME

    info
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    dataframe()

  })
}
```

and i Get the follow error:

```
Error: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

I am doing it in local.

Thanks

Comment: Is `input$text` supposed to be the file path to the Access Database?  If so, you should probably be using `con <- odbcConnectAccess(input$text)`. `renderPrint` is used to create an output slot to be displayed in the UI.

Comment: You should post reproducible example! or at least what is input$text

Answer (score 0):

As Benjammin note:

server.R

```
  function(input, output) {

      dataframe <- eventReactive(input$do, {

      con <- odbcConnectAccess(input$text)
      info <- sqlTables(channel = con, tableType = "TABLE")$TABLE_NAME
      info

    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
      dataframe()

    })
  }
```

input$text is the file path to the Access DDBB.